# quiver3 arrow color corresponding to magnitude

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want the color of each arrow in a `quiver3` plot from MATLAB to correspond to the magnitude of each arrow. Is there any way to do that?

I saw a few examples online that are able to do this for the 2D `quiver`, however none of them work for the 3D variant, `quiver3`.

I have the following plot and want to replace the blue arrows with a color corresponding to their magnitude.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid your best bet would be to modify [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3225-quiverc) submission to the File Exchange to manage the 3D case...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the old graphics system (R2014a and earlier) this is not possible using the built-in `quiver` object. You can easily get all of the plot objects that are used to compose the `quiver` plot

```
q = quiver(1:5, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5);
handles = findall(q, 'type', 'line');
```

But the tails are all represented by one plot object, and the arrow heads are represented by another. As such, you can't alter the color of each head/tail *individually*.

```
set(handles(1), 'Color', 'r')
set(handles(2), 'Color', 'g')
```

[image]

However, with the introduction of HG2 (R2014b and later), you can actually get access to *two* (undocumented) `LineStrip` objects (`matlab.graphics.primitive.world.LineStrip`) (one represents the heads and one represents the tails). These are accessible via the hidden properties `Tail` and `Head`.

```
q = quiver(1, 1, 1, 1);
headLineStrip = q.Head;
tailLineStrip = q.Tail;
```

You can then alter the color properties of these objects to make each arrow a different color.

## The Basic Idea

To do this, I first compute the magnitude of all quiver arrows (this works for both `quiver` and `quiver3`)

```
mags = sqrt(sum(cat(2, q.UData(:), q.VData(:), ...
            reshape(q.WData, numel(q.UData), [])).^2, 2));
```

Then I use the current colormap to map each magnitude to an RGB value. The shortest arrow is assigned the lowest color on the colormap and the longest arrow is assigned the highest color on the colormap. `histcounts` works great for assigning each magnitude an index which can be passed to `ind2rgb` along with the colormap itself. We have to multiply by 255 because we need the color to be RGB as an 8-bit integer.

```
% Get the current colormap
currentColormap = colormap(gca);

% Now determine the color to make each arrow using a colormap
[~, ~, ind] = histcounts(mags, size(currentColormap, 1));

% Now map this to a colormap
cmap = uint8(ind2rgb(ind(:), currentColormap) * 255);
```

The `LineStrip` `ColorData` property (when specified as `truecolor`) also needs to have an alpha channel (which we will set to 255 meaning opaque).

```
cmap(:,:,4) = 255;
```

At this point we can then set the `ColorBinding` property to `interpolated` rather than `object` (to decouple it from the `quiver` object) and set the `ColorData` property of both `q.Head` and `q.Tail` to the colors we created above giving each arrow it's own color.

## Full Solution

**NOTE:** This solution works for *both* `quiver` and `quiver3` and the code does not have to be adapted at all.

```
%// Create a quiver3 as we normally would (could also be 2D quiver)

x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z = zeros(size(X));
U = zeros(size(X));
V = zeros(size(X));
W = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2);

q = quiver3(X, Y, Z, U, V, W);

%// Compute the magnitude of the vectors
mags = sqrt(sum(cat(2, q.UData(:), q.VData(:), ...
            reshape(q.WData, numel(q.UData), [])).^2, 2));

%// Get the current colormap
currentColormap = colormap(gca);

%// Now determine the color to make each arrow using a colormap
[~, ~, ind] = histcounts(mags, size(currentColormap, 1));

%// Now map this to a colormap to get RGB
cmap = uint8(ind2rgb(ind(:), currentColormap) * 255);
cmap(:,:,4) = 255;
cmap = permute(repmat(cmap, [1 3 1]), [2 1 3]);

%// We repeat each color 3 times (using 1:3 below) because each arrow has 3 vertices
set(q.Head, ...
    'ColorBinding', 'interpolated', ...
    'ColorData', reshape(cmap(1:3,:,:), [], 4).');   %'

%// We repeat each color 2 times (using 1:2 below) because each tail has 2 vertices
set(q.Tail, ...
    'ColorBinding', 'interpolated', ...
    'ColorData', reshape(cmap(1:2,:,:), [], 4).');
```

[image]

And applied to a 2D `quiver` object

[image]

If you don't necessarily want to scale the arrows to the entire range of the colormap you could use the following call to `histcounts` (instead of the line above) to map the magnitudes using the color limits of the axes.

```
clims = num2cell(get(gca, 'clim'));
[~, ~, ind] = histcounts(mags, linspace(clims{:}, size(currentColormap, 1)));
```

Comment: Excellent! Yet it fails when there are NaNs in `U`, `V` or `W`. This can be simply corrected by replacing all `NaN`s by zeros before the call to `quiver`/`quiver3`.

Answer (score 6):

If your using a post r2014b version you can use undocumented features to change the colour of each line and head:

```
figure
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2:.5:2,-1:.5:1);
z = x .* exp(-x.^2 - y.^2);
[u,v,w] = surfnorm(x,y,z);
h=quiver3(x,y,z,u,v,w); 

s = size(x);
nPoints = s(1)*s(2);
% create a colour map
cmap = parula(nPoints);
% x2 because each point has 2 points, a start and an end.
cd = uint8(repmat([255 0 0 255]', 1, nPoints*2));
count = 0;
% we need to assign a colour per point
for ii=1:nPoints
  % and we need to assign a colour to the start and end of the 
  %   line.
  for jj=1:2
    count = count + 1;
    cd(1:3,count) = uint8(255*cmap(ii,:)');
  end
end
% set the colour binding method and the colour data of the tail
set(h.Tail, 'ColorBinding','interpolated', 'ColorData',cd)

% create a color matrix for the heads
cd = uint8(repmat([255 0 0 255]', 1, nPoints*3));
count = 0;
% we need to assign a colour per point
for ii=1:nPoints
  % and we need to assign a colour to the all the points 
  %   at the head of the arrow
  for jj=1:3
    count = count + 1;
    cd(1:3,count) = uint8(255*cmap(ii,:)');
  end
end
% set the colour binding method and the colour data of the head
set(h.Head, 'ColorBinding','interpolated', 'ColorData',cd)
```

Note: I've not done anything clever with the magnitude and simply change the colour of each quiver based on the order in the original matrix - but you should be able to get the idea on how to use this "feature"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using Suevers solution and have NaNs in your data you should include this line before calling histcounts:

```
mags(isnan(mags)) = [];
```

Otherwise you will get an error about wrong input size because matlab does not create vertices for NaNs in your U/V/W data.