# Plotting normals (quivers) with individual color

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix of normals **`N`** at their corresponding locations **`L`**, for example calculated by the function *pcnormals*. I can now plot the normals at their location using the *quiver3* function. This all works fine, but what if I wanted to colorize the normals (i.e., their respective plotted quivers) according to their angle to some other vector?

I have not found any possibility of doing so with the *quiver3* function. Have I missed something or can I achieve my goal with another function?

**Example:**

```
load('object3d.mat');
normals = pcnormals(ptCloud);
x = ptCloud.Location(1:10:end,1:10:end,1);
y = ptCloud.Location(1:10:end,1:10:end,2);
z = ptCloud.Location(1:10:end,1:10:end,3);
u = normals(1:10:end,1:10:end,1);
v = normals(1:10:end,1:10:end,2);
w = normals(1:10:end,1:10:end,3);
quiver3(x,y,z,u,v,w);   % this plots the normals with one color
% calculate the angle to some other vector
sensorCenter = [0,0,0];
angles = zeros(numel(x),1);
for k = 1 : numel(x)
   p1 = sensorCenter - [x(k),y(k),z(k)];
   p2 = [u(k),v(k),w(k)];
   % Flip the normal vector if it is not pointing towards the sensor.
   angle = atan2(norm(cross(p1,p2)),p1*p2');
   if angle > pi/2 || angle < -pi/2
       u(k) = -u(k);
       v(k) = -v(k);
       w(k) = -w(k);
       if angle > pi/2, angle = angle - pi/2; end
       if angle < -pi/2, angle = angle + pi/2; end
   end
   angles(k) = angle;
end
% know we have a vector of angles containing values between 0 and pi/2
% TODO: color quivers according to value in angles
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/269970
I think it might work!

Comment: Please post example code and a screenshort.

Comment: @16per9: well, this would translate to plotting all quivers one after another with different color using hold on; in between. This would be very slow, I am sure.

Comment: @thewaywewalk: I did now :)

Comment: There is a bounty for this exact problem in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632430/matlab-colored-quiver3-plot

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Oh wow, I did not find this question. Thank you :)

Comment: @user1809923 There is now an answer over on the post linked above by Ander. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: @Suever: Awesome! I applied your solution to my problem and it works very nicely, thanks :)