# MATLAB quiver3 colormap

Tags: matlab, scatter, colormap

I have a quiver3 plot on MATLAB with the code and plot as following, and I would like the lines to be color-variant as they approach the center point (which is cyan blue), so that I could visulize their distances from the center. Any idea how could I do that? Thanks so much!

```
hold on;
grid on;
scatter3(frame_cur.xyz_cam(1,:),frame_cur.xyz_cam(2,:),frame_cur.xyz_cam(3,:),'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .75 .75]);
quiver3(frameGT_cur.xyz_cam(1,:),                  ...
        frameGT_cur.xyz_cam(2,:),                  ...
        frameGT_cur.xyz_cam(3,:),                  ...
        C(1,:)-frame_cur.xyz_cam(1,:),     ...
        C(2,:)-frame_cur.xyz_cam(2,:),     ...
        C(3,:)-frame_cur.xyz_cam(3,:),     ...
        0,'b','ShowArrowHead','off');*
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt this is possible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632430/quiver3-arrow-color-corresponding-to-magnitude/36940596

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not using `quiver3` but the result is close to what you requested. this answer is inspired by [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5042-how-do-i-vary-color-along-a-2d-line).

I used `surf` with the name-value arguments `'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','interp'` to create lines with interpolating color:

```
% generate random 3D points
n = 10;
x = 2*rand(n,1)-1;
y = 2*rand(n,1)-1;
z = 2*rand(n,1)-1;
% the color is the distance of each point
c = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2); 
% plot the points
scatter3(x,y,z,40,c,'filled');
hold on
% add zeros (the center point) between points
xx = [zeros(1,numel(x));x(:)'];xx = xx(:);
yy = [zeros(1,numel(y));y(:)'];yy = yy(:);
zz = [zeros(1,numel(z));z(:)'];zz = zz(:);
cc = [zeros(1,numel(c));c(:)'];cc = cc(:);
% plot the lines
h = surf([xx,xx],[yy,yy],[zz,zz],[cc,cc],...
    'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','interp','LineWidth',1);
colorbar;
```

[image]