# How to visualize a vector rotating in 3D in MatLab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to visualize how my spin density rotates in space using MatLab. As far as I've been able to investigate, there are feather and quiver3 environments for this kind of purpose, if I'm not mistaken. What I'm looking for is that you can follow the evolution with arrows as graphic indicators.

My three components of the vector depend on a single variable, let's call it x, and even one of its components is zero:

```
x=[0:0.01:10]
Sxy=0;
Syy=(cos(sqrt(2*sqrt(2)+1)*x)+(sqrt(7)/(11+8*sqrt(2)))*sin(sqrt(2*sqrt(2)+1)*x)).*exp(-sqrt(2*sqrt(2)-1)*x);
Szy=-(2/(77+56*sqrt(2)))*(-7*sqrt(1+2*sqrt(2))+11*sqrt(-7+14*sqrt(2))+8*sqrt(-14+28*sqrt(2)))*exp(-sqrt(2*sqrt(2)-1)*x).*sin(sqrt(2*sqrt(2)+1)*x);
```

Any suggestions on how it can be done?

Comment: You need to have positions (x,y,z) for quiver.....x is given..how about (y,z) ?

Comment: It is true that they are not specified, that's because my variables do not depend on y and z ... Maybe it's clearer what I want to do if I show you a similar graph that I could get with Mathematica   https://ibb.co/eBtpo8

Answer (score 0):

You have `x` locations of the arrows and their components in 3 dims, but you need 3 components for their origin, (`x`,`y`,`z`). They can be zero though.

```
q=quiver3(x,zeros(size(x)),zeros(size(x)),Sxy*ones(size(x)),Syy,Szy,0); % last zero sets autoscale of arrows
```

But maybe you want something more, stylish? Add this in the bottom:

I used the [viridis colormap](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632430/quiver3-arrow-color-corresponding-to-magnitude) answer.

```
set(q,'MaxHeadSize',0.03,'AutoScaleFactor',0);
set(q,'LineWidth',2);
%// Compute the magnitude of the vectors
mags = sqrt(sum(cat(2, q.UData(:), q.VData(:), ...
            reshape(q.WData, numel(q.UData), [])).^2, 2));

%// Get the current colormap
currentColormap = colormap(viridis);

%// Now determine the color to make each arrow using a colormap
[~, ~, ind] = histcounts(mags, size(currentColormap, 1));

%// Now map this to a colormap to get RGB
cmap = uint8(ind2rgb(ind(:), currentColormap) * 255);
cmap(:,:,4) = 255;
cmap = permute(repmat(cmap, [1 3 1]), [2 1 3]);

%// We repeat each color 3 times (using 1:3 below) because each arrow has 3 vertices
set(q.Head, ...
    'ColorBinding', 'interpolated', ...
    'ColorData', reshape(cmap(1:3,:,:), [], 4).');   %'

%// We repeat each color 2 times (using 1:2 below) because each tail has 2 vertices
set(q.Tail, ...
    'ColorBinding', 'interpolated', ...
    'ColorData', reshape(cmap(1:2,:,:), [], 4).');
```

[image]